# Does the salary calculator take into account regional data?

Tags: feature-request, salary-calculator

I often hear salaries are low due to lower cost of living or a rural area or economically depressed area or just generally crappiness of an area. Does the calculator take anything related to that into account, or is it just based on the closest major city?

Comment: I haven't looked at the calculator at all today but I will say - I worked at a company where I made an **equivalent** CoL salary to someone working in Colombia.  I was getting paid about **three times** what they were.  Note that I live in the United States.  You should be careful at how you define "major city"; I would consider Medellín to be a "major city".

Comment: Put another way, I wonder if the estimate for a small town is based on data points for only that area, or is it based on derived data that accounts for (or not) the difference in CoL for that area, if that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/05/developer-salaries-in-2018-updating-the-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/) for the most detailed information about how regional information is handled. We built a model that has separate predictions for different countries, for example, for Poland, Sweden, and France. Within many of these countries, we had enough respondents to build separate predictions for metro areas where developers earn more, such as London (in the UK) and Berlin (in Germany). We did not have enough respondents in rural areas to build a *lower* prediction for any country, but read the blog post for a more detailed explanation with plots.